# camel 3 : addRoutesBuilder & spring-main incompatible?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm in migration of a program Came 2.25 to 3.20.4, and there is something i can't fix.

It seems like camel-spring-main & addRoutesBuilder can't work together...

springcontext.xml

```
<camel:camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
</camel:camelContext>
```

MyMain.java (part)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Main main = new org.apache.camel.spring.Main();
        main.setApplicationContextUri("springcontext.xml");
        main.configure().addRoutesBuilder(new Route1());
        main.configure().addRoutesBuilder(new Route2());
        if (condition3)
            main.configure().addRoutesBuilder(new Route3());
        if (condition4)
            main.configure().addRoutesBuilder(new Route4());
        main.run();
```

Behavior with 2.25 : the log says `Total 0 routes, of which 0 are started` and just after, i see the routes in my classes Route1..Route4 start (seen by `Route: Route1 started and consuming from:...` ) 
and only the wanted routes depending on the conditions.

Behavior with 3.20.4 : when i start my app, i see `Routes startup (started:0)`, and nothing after that.

I also tested to add `<packageScan>` in the camelContext, With that, all the routes starts OK, but no conditions possible...

How can i have a situation like old 2.25 ?